# MySQL: How to SELECT depending on availability in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have to tables called `books` and `authors`.

This is my `books` table:

[image: books table]

It contains title of the book, the authors name and a description of the book.

This is my `authors` table:

[image: authors table]

It contains the authors name, the city where the author lives and an author portrait (description).

My question is: How can I `SELECT *` rows from `books` where the authors city is established as e.g. `Berlin` in the `authors` table.

In this case, when city=Berlin, the rows with `title = "Something title AAA"` and `title = "Something title DDD"` should get selected.

This is what I've tried:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT title, author, description FROM books JOIN authors ON :city = city');

$stmt->execute(array(':city' => "Berlin"));
```

But it's not working. I'm getting no output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, `ON :city` that's where things start to *"go South"*. You can't bind it that way because PDO doesn't know what to do ahead of time. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php would have thrown you something about it.

Comment: Hint:  The `JOIN` condition is on the author not on the city.

Comment: So, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the result of the following query:

```
SELECT books.* FROM books INNER JOIN authors ON books.author = authors.name
WHERE authors.city = 'Berlin'
```

with PHP / PDO it looks like the following:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT books.* FROM books INNER JOIN authors ON books.author = authors.name WHERE authors.city = :city');
$stmt->execute(array(':city' => "Berlin"));
```

The `ON` part of the query defines the relationship between your tables `books` and `authors`. After this joining you can imagine the two tables as one big table with all columns. On the `WHERE` part of the query you define the filter to get all `books` where the author comes from a specified `:city` (in your example Berlin).